# Transition between multiple views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I want to show multiple views one after another to show multiple values when the user slides his finger on the screen, just like photo album. I want the same animation. Can anyone explain how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the images in an array... By using the [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can able to do the photo album.... if you have any doubt communicate with me...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at one of the WWDC 2010 sessions, I believe it was called "Designing apps with scroll views", it basically builds the exact thing your looking for with UIScrollViews. Take a look at the video and the sample code - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=104 and the sample code should be here http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

PS! You have to be a iPhone Developer to access this content.